# Bar chart from data in one column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Call me stupid but every time I want to perform an easy task in Excel I end up using Google to find a solution. Today's mission impossible is to create a bar(or pie) chart from data located in one column.

Say I have this data:

```
A
---
John
John
Max
Peter
Sally
John
Max
Alex
John
```

I just want a bar chart from column A with 6 bars telling me how many times (Y-axis) a name occured in that column. John would have a bar with value/height 4, Max 2, Peter, Sally, Max and Alex 1.

How can this be achieved without the use of a pivot chart or adding an extra column to create a count-value. This should be possible straight forward, right?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I've tried to add a normal chart. I think its redundant to add another table with the data in order to display the chart because the data is already on the sheet.

Comment: ... A chart renders a table based upon the format of the table!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data on the sheet isn't in a format that an Excel chart would recognise nor be able to do anything with without some help.

You need to provide a count of these values and provide this as data for the chart.  You can't expect that just by providing a list of text data, Excel would know what you want to do with it.

Sometimes, unfortunately, you have to do a little more work to get the data in a format that Excel can process.  In this case, it's not a massive amount of work to get what you need.

Comment: True, I will do that. I assumed it seemed clumsy. Thank you.